# Why is this minHeap implementation incorrect?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, priority-queue, min-heap

I am using a PriorityQueue to solve the Meeting Rooms II problem from Leetcode. I have developed my own solution that fails on certain test cases, yet from my eyes it is indistinguishable from the provided solution, yet that solution passes all tests. What is the difference between the two? The main difference I see is with the passed comparator to the minHeap, but my understanding was that a PriorityQueue by default would keep the smallest number at the head.

Given Solution:

```
    public int minMeetingRooms(int[][] intervals) {
        
    // Check for the base case. If there are no intervals, return 0
    if (intervals.length == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    // Min heap
    PriorityQueue<Integer> allocator =
        new PriorityQueue<Integer>(
            intervals.length,
            new Comparator<Integer>() {
              public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
                return a - b;
              }
            });

    // Sort the intervals by start time
    Arrays.sort(
        intervals,
        new Comparator<int[]>() {
          public int compare(final int[] a, final int[] b) {
            return a[0] - b[0];
          }
        });

    // Add the first meeting
    allocator.add(intervals[0][1]);

    // Iterate over remaining intervals
    for (int i = 1; i < intervals.length; i++) {

      // If the room due to free up the earliest is free, assign that room to this meeting.
      if (intervals[i][0] >= allocator.peek()) {
        allocator.poll();
      }

      // If a new room is to be assigned, then also we add to the heap,
      // If an old room is allocated, then also we have to add to the heap with updated end time.
      allocator.add(intervals[i][1]);
    }

    // The size of the heap tells us the minimum rooms required for all the meetings.
    return allocator.size();
  }
}
```

My Implementation:

```
    public int minMeetingRooms(int[][] intervals) {
        if (intervals.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        Comparator<int[]> comp = new Comparator<int[]>(){
          public int compare(int[] A, int[] B){
              if(A[0]<B[0]){
                 return -1; 
              }
              else if(A[0]>B[0]){
                  return 0;
              } 
              else{
                  return 1;
              } 
          }  
        };
        Arrays.sort(intervals, comp);
        PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        minHeap.add(intervals[0][1]);
        for(int i = 1; i<intervals.length; i++){   
            if(intervals[i][0] >= minHeap.peek()){
                minHeap.poll();
            }
            minHeap.add(intervals[i][1]);
        }
        return minHeap.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
          else if(A[0]>B[0]){
              return 0;
          }
```

should be

```
          else if(A[0] == B[0]){
              return 0;
          }
```

You should return 0 if they're equal.

Comment: Or, easier than all the conditionals, `return Integer.compare(A[0], B[0]);`.

Comment: Or just use `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0])`. It’s also worth noting that the given solution’s comparators are broken as well, as minus can overflow. And specifying a comparator for `Integer` is entirely unnecessary when the resulting order matching the natural order.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is going to wrong way. Your condition should be **`IF(no1[0] == no2[0]) THEN return 0`**, **`IF(no1[0] > no2[0]) THEN return 1 ELSE return -1`**

**Change**

```
if(A[0] < B[0])
  return -1; 
else if(A[0] > B[0])
  return 0; 
else
  return 1;
```

**To**

```
if(A[0] == B[0])
  return 0; 

if(A[0] > B[0])
  return 1;
else
  return -1;
```